# How does the \$Q\$-factor of a parallel RCL circuit scale with the inductance?

Tags: function

I want to be able to show in an expression that the $Q$-factor of a parallel RCL circuit scales with the inductance. If we remind ourselves of a RCL circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWXXfr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The \$Q\$-factor is defined as 
$$Q = \frac{\omega_{0}}{\Delta\omega} = 2 \pi \frac{E}{\Delta E}$$
and is a statement about the amount of energy lost from the system in one cycle of oscillation. With $$\Delta\omega = 1/ C R$$

The resistance \$R\$ can be shown to be 
$$ R = \omega_0 Q L$$

The resonance frequency, \$\omega_0\$, scales as
$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C L}}$$

If I think about what happens physically, it makes sense that the energy stored in the system is defined by the inductor -- this is also what my experiments have shown. If I increase the inductance then I increase the \$Q\$-factor.

I'd like to be able to show the a function that describes the \$Q\$-factor as a function of \$L\$: \$Q(L)\$. This seems easy enough but I encounter circular problems because the \$Q\$-factor is embedded into many of the definitions I have listed, the resistance \$R\$ is especially problematic.

Comment: Please give some examples of your experimental results. And do you want a theoretical derivation? Finally, please note that inductors may have a significant resistance component.

Comment: It scales with the square root of inductance.

Comment: @Andyaka can you show an explicit form, and how you arrived at that. My calculations so far show it is linear with \$L\$. As \$Q = \omega_{0} L / R_{s}\$ where \$R_{s}\$ is a residual series resistance coming from the components which the circuit is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the left-side source, as I think you are trying to focus on the following three ideal components in the shown arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkJyh1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The nodal equation is (a positive current points downwards through a component):

$$\frac{V_\text{N}}{R}+\frac{1}{L}\int V_\text{N}\:\text{d}t+C\,\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{N}}{\text{d}t}=0\:\text{A}$$

Taking the derivative and dividing through by \$C\$ :

$$\begin{align*}\frac{\text{d}^2\,V_\text{N}}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{1}{R\:C}\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{N}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{V_\text{N}}{L\:C}&=0\:\text{A}\end{align*}$$

The characteristic equation is:

$$s^2+\frac{s}{R\:C}+\frac{1}{L\:C}=0$$

Solving with the standard quadratic solution equation, \$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4\:a\:c}}{2\:a}\$, we find that it is convenient (from a cursory examination of the results) to define:

$$\begin{align*}\alpha&=\frac{1}{2\:R\:C}&\omega_{_0}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L\:C}}\\\\&\text{and the unitless }\zeta=\frac{\alpha}{\omega_{_0}},\text{ where }Q=\frac1{2\,\zeta}.\end{align*}$$

The solutions are:

$$\begin{align*}\left\{\begin{array}{l}s_{_1}=-\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega_{_0}^2}=\omega_{_0}\left[-\zeta+\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right]\\s_{_2}=-\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\omega_{_0}^2}=\omega_{_0}\left[-\zeta-\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\right]\end{array}\right.\end{align*}$$

(The right side expression is why \$\zeta\$ or \$Q\$ are so valuable for 2nd order equations. They are unitless and create a factor that is applied to \$\omega_{_0}\$, which carries the units.)

The damping factor conditions:

$$\begin{align*}\left\{\begin{array}{l}\zeta = 1 \left(\alpha=\omega_{_0}\right)&&\text{Critically damped}\\\zeta \gt 1 \left(\alpha\gt \omega_{_0}\right)&&\text{Over-damped}\\\zeta \lt 1 \left(\alpha\lt \omega_{_0}\right)&&\text{Under-damped}\\\zeta = 0&&\text{Un-damped}\end{array}\right.\end{align*}$$

Anyway, from the above you can readily see that \$Q=\omega_{_0}\,R\,C=R\,\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}\$. You can find the same result in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor#RLC_circuits).

---

(None of this accounts for the likely Ohmic resistance in the inductor, \$L\$. But adding it is simple and the above process would be the same, just with another variable added and some additional work.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: -

[image]

On the left is the parallel arrangement of R. On the right is the inductor's series R arrangement.

If you go to wiki RLC circuit you’ll get a bigger run down of things.

Comment: Thanks! But for me here's where things become a bit circular, \$R = \omega_{0} L Q\$ this is the parallel resistance -- so maybe you can see where my confusion emerges.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are driving at. Have you checked out the wiki site I mentioned?

Comment: I did but if you consider a helical resonator in a cylindrical shield then the parallel resistance of this (\$R\$ in my diagram) is define by the relation in my comment. So then your expression becomes recursive. If I am still not clear enough I will derive my R as an edit in my question. Cheers!